# Does "the use of A and B" require a plural or singular verb?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

I am correcting an academic text and am in doubt about which of these two sentences is correct:

> Considering the main sources of the yield gap for sugarcane in India, the use of drought tolerant cultivars and irrigation **seem** to be the best **strategies** to mitigate the risks.

or

> Considering the main sources of the yield gap for sugarcane in India, the use of drought tolerant cultivars and irrigation **seems** to be the best **strategy** to mitigate the risks.

Comment: Singular verb. Also, to mitigate risks. Not the risks.

Comment: Think of it as, "The use ___ to be the best ______". Now what seems right?

Comment: @Lambie, thanks for the two tips! And Hank, indeed, it that case "The use seems to be the best strategy". =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the singular here: *seems*. The reason is that the subject of the verb is singular: *use*.

Removing the genitive should make things clearer:

> The use seems to be the best strategy.

In the example sentence, though, it depends on what exactly the subject is. It's possible, if unlikely, to read it thus:

> A. [The use of X] and B. irrigation -> SEEM to be the best strategies.

This way, you have two subjects, the first being "the use" and the second being "irrigation."

Comment: There is no second reading possible. It should be singular, yes.

Comment: @Lambie: What do you mean? “[the use of A] and [B]” is certainly a syntactically possible parse that would be a plural noun phrase.